# How to convert Table format to Bootstrap column format?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Am migrating existing table-based content to `Bootstrap`.

Have an existing table (version-1) in the following logical format. It is a table within a table.

```
<table-1>
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|    <td-1>    |           |        |        |    <td-5>    |
|              | <table-2> |        |        |              |
|              | <td-2>    | <td-3> | <td-4> |              |
|              |-----------|--------|--------|              |
|              |           |        |        |              |
|              |-----------|--------|--------|              |
|              |           |        |        |              |
|              |-----------|--------|--------|              |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
</table-1>
```

My plan for version-2 is to use Bootstrap like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
...
```

achieving a 3 column layout like this:

```
|<- col-md-3 ->| <----     col-md-6    ---->|<- col-md-3 ->|
```

**How to translate the inner table (table-2) cell format (specifically   ) into bootstrap layout?**

*Some additional information*:

Table-2 formats dynamic content - content from a `JSON` file.
So the number of rows for table-2 varies by the number of items in the `JSON` file.

The items that are inserted in the logical cells are images. My goal is that Bootstrap displays the number of images based on the width of the display (fewer if portrait, more if landscape).

Here is my Bootstrap initialization:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I believe this is the correct initialization, but please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: did you try to use dataTables of Bootstrap

Comment: I was not familar with dataTables. But in checking the docs, I think it requires JavaScript. I'd like to find an HTML solution.

Comment: use this awesome datatables, https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap

Comment: The inner table formats a series of images. I want the number of images on a logical row to vary according to the width of the display. For example, portrait may display 3 images, but landscape may display 6 images.